# Get the record type name instead of Record Type id in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components

I want to display two fields based on record types when i am hard coding the values I am getting the out .Instead of hardcoding the value i want to compare using record type name.
Any suggestions on this to get the record type name instead of id ??

HTML:

```
template>
    <lightning-card  icon-name="standard:investment_account"   variant="narrow"   title="tactic data" >
      <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Campaign">
         <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
              <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                <lightning-output-field field-name="field1" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-output-field>
                  <lightning-output-field field-name="field2"></lightning-output-field>
                    <template if:true={isRecordTypeB}>
                      <lightning-output-field field-name="field3"></lightning-output-field>
                    </template>                 
                          </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                       <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                     <lightning-output-field field-name="field4" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-output-field>
                   <lightning-output-field field-name="field5"></lightning-output-field>
                   <template if:true={IsRecordTypeA}>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="field6"></lightning-output-field>
                </template>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </lightning-record-view-form>    
    </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement ,api,track,wire} from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CAMPAIGN_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/campaign';
//import RECORDTYPEID from '@salesforce/schema/campaign.RecordTypeId';
//const _FIELDS = [RECORDTYPEID];
import { getRecord,getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
export default class EDMtacticfields extends LightningElement {
   @api recordId;
   @track RecordType;
   @api objectApiName;
   @track objectInfo;

    @wire(getObjectInfo,  { objectApiName: CAMPAIGN_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: _FIELDS })
    campaign;

    get recordTypeName() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        const rtId = getFieldValue(this.campaign.data,  RECORDTYPEID);
        this.RecordType = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].id === rtId);
        return this.RecordType;
       
        console.log('Recordtype Name--->'+this.RecordType);
    }
    get isRecordTypeB() {
        console.log('Recordtype1--->'+this.RecordType);
        if(this.RecordType==='B')
        return true;
        return false;
    }

    get isRecordTypeA() {   
        console.log('Recordtype2--->'+this.RRecordType);
        if(this.RecordType==='A')  
            return true;
            return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getObjectInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info) to get the record types by ID and name. It will require a separate wire call, but once loaded, you'll know the record types by name and ID.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

I tried as below but not getting the output.


    get recordTypeName() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        const rtId = getFieldValue(this.campaign.data,  RECORDTYPEID);
        this.RecordType = Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].id === rtId);
        return this.RecordType;
       
        console.log('Recordtype Name--->'+this.RecordType);
    }

Answer (score 1):

We can simply get record type details of current record in the page using below code.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: ['Case.RecordType.Name'] })
getCaseRecord({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        let recordTypeDetails = data.fields['RecordType']; //this line has record type Id and Name.
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, simple and easy. It only display the label, and not the developerName tho.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code and got  the required output.

JS:

```
import { LightningElement ,api,track,wire} from 'lwc';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import CAMPAIGN_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/campaign';
import RECORDTYPEID from '@salesforce/schema/campaign.RecordTypeId';
const _FIELDS = [RECORDTYPEID];
import { getRecord,getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
export default class EDMtacticfields extends LightningElement {
   @api recordId;
   @track RecordType;
   @api objectApiName;
   @track objectInfo;
   @track error;
   @track record;
 

    @wire(getObjectInfo,  { objectApiName: CAMPAIGN_OBJECT })
    ObjectInfo;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: _FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
           this.record = data;
          this.RecordType = this.record.fields.RecordTypeId.value;
           this.error = undefined;
       } else if (error) {
          this.error = error;
           this.record = undefined;
     }
    }
   

   get isrecordTypeNameB() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.ObjectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        const rtInfo= Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'B');
        
        if(this.RecordType===rtInfo){
            return true;
            console.log('Checking recordtype name----->'+this.RecordType);
            console.log('Checking recordtype name1----->'+this.rtInfo);
        } else{
            return false;
        }  
        
    }
    get isrecordTypeNameA() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.ObjectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        //const rtId = getFieldValue(this.wiredRecord.record,  RECORDTYPEID);
        const rtInfo= Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'A');
       
        
        if(this.RecordType===rtInfo){
            return true;
            console.log('Checking recordtype name2----->'+this.RecordType);
            console.log('Checking recordtype name3----->'+this.rtInfo);
        } else{
            return false;
        }  
        
    }
```

HTML:

```
template>
    <lightning-card  icon-name="standard:investment_account"   variant="narrow"   title="tactic data" >
      <lightning-record-view-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Campaign">
         <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
           <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
              <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                <lightning-output-field field-name="field1" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-output-field>
                  <lightning-output-field field-name="field2"></lightning-output-field>
                    <template if:true={ObjectInfo.data}>
                   <template if:true={isrecordTypeNameB}>
                      <lightning-output-field field-name="field3"></lightning-output-field>
                    </template>   
                    </template>               
                          </div>
                         </div>
                         <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                       <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
                     <lightning-output-field field-name="field4" class="slds-m-right_x-small"></lightning-output-field>
                   <lightning-output-field field-name="field5"></lightning-output-field>
                   <template if:true={ObjectInfo.data}>
                   <template if:true={isrecordTypeNameB}>
                 <lightning-output-field field-name="field6"></lightning-output-field>
                </template>
                </template> 
              </div>
            </div>
         </div>
       </lightning-record-view-form>    
    </lightning-card>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The record type name is returned directly from the `getRecord` wire.  The output from the `getRecord` call has the following shape:

```json
{
    "apiName": "Contact",
    "childRelationships": {},
    "id": "003xxx",
    "lastModifiedById": "005xxx",
    "lastModifiedDate": "2022-06-09T16:04:10.000Z",
    "recordTypeId": "012xxx",
    "recordTypeInfo": {
        "available": true,
        "defaultRecordTypeMapping": true,
        "master": false,
        "name": "myrecordtypename",
        "recordTypeId": "012fxxx"
    },
    "systemModstamp": "2022-06-09T16:04:10.000Z",
    "fields": {
        "Name": {
            "displayValue": null,
            "value": "John Doe"
        }
    }
}
```